# Visual Studio 2015 call stack displays <Unknown function>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Recently after doing a clean install of Windows 10 Pro on my computer, I noticed that whenever I break my program and open the call stack, the call stack shows the application name and line numbers, but the function name is displayed as `<Unknown function>`. The call stack can be navigated as usual, but the missing function names are very annoying.

I've tried the following:

- Made sure that I'm running a debug build with full symbol generation
- Confirmed that all relevant debug symbols are loaded
- Tried completely reinstalling Visual Studio (3 times)
- Resetting all my Visual Studio settings to the defaults
- Deleting/cleaning build and user-specific files
- Making sure my Visual Studio is up-to-date (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

Even creating a new Win32 C++ console application from the default template and breaking on the `return 0;` nets `<Unknown function>`'s in the call stack.

Example:
[image: Example].

How would I make the call stack display the correct function names?

Comment: I seriously hope this is not a "re-install 2015" class of bug.  You do have all the latest hotfixes for it yes?

Comment: I have not seen that. Just curious are the functions internal to your project or are they in some other library?

Comment: ***deleting/cleaning build and user-specific files*** Did this include deleting the entire Debug folder of your project?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thank you, added to the post along with the version number.

Comment: @drescherjm They are internal and written by me. In the example screenshot I set a breakpoint on the first line of the main() function. And yes, that includes the Debug folder (in the example). For my own project the build files for VS are generated by CMake, thus I deleted **all** the build files and the cached files and regenerated them. There was no difference.

Comment: If you deleted the PDB file, then the debugger will not be able to match line numbers to functions. Rebuild the project to recreate it.

Comment: @CodyGray `Confirmed that all relevant debug symbols are loaded`, that includes the symbols (.pdb) generated for my application. But as my answer mentions, this is caused by a mysteriously missing .dll file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the missing `cppdebug.dll` and `cppdebug.vsdconfig` from the `Common7\Packages\Debugger`, as Patrick suspected. Visual Studio unfortunately gives no indication of them missing being a problem and reinstalling or repairing the installation doesn't help either. Fortunately, I was able to obtain those files through other means.
Placing the files equivalent to your Visual Studio version fixes the problem.

`cppdebug.dll` and `cppdebug.vsdconfig` for different Visual Studio versions:

- [15.0.21215.1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/pn4923aulzr14g8/15.0.21215.1+cppdebug.7z)
- [14.0.25431.1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/cd90ap9z7olrh24/14.0.25431.1+cppdebug.rar)
- [14.0.25425.1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6yonts77mat5of3/14.0.25425.1+cppdebug.rar)
- [14.0.25420.1](http://www.mediafire.com/file/a9ms2n7s563hdrr/14.0.25420.1+cppdebug.rar)
- [14.0.25123.0](http://www.mediafire.com/file/sscwx1wfvd31tsb/14.0.25123.0+cppdebug.rar)
- [14.0.24720.0](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1f1qc6hzt16gtds/14.0.24720.0+cppdebug.rar)

Answer (score 2):

This error message means the component of the debugger which formats the text for C++ stack frames is failing.  I've seen this happen when the installer leaves Visual Studio with mismatching binaries.  Here are things I would try:

1. First make sure this isn't being caused by a faulty extension by running VS in safe mode via `devenv.exe /safemode` see [Visual Studio Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx).
2. Uninstall any VS extensions, then uninstall VS and make sure all files are deleted from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger` (may need to change the path if you installed VS somewhere else), then try reinstalling.
3. If that doesn't fix it, then you may have a problem with your Windows install.  You can try running `depends.exe` on `cppdebug.dll` and see if you can determine which dependency is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Launching in safemode unfortunately didn't help. I uninstalled VS2015, deleted all the leftovers and reinstalled. Unfortunately the problems still persisted. From what I found, cppdebug.dll should be located under Common7\Packages\Debugger, but it's not there. I also ran a search through the whole VS2015 installation and was unable to find it. How should I proceed?

Comment: cppdebug.dll is missing from Common7\Packages\Debugger?  That would be a problem.  What about cppdebug.vsdconfig?  I can't explain why the installer wouldn't be installing it.  You might try re-downloading the installer.  Repairing the install should also put the file back.

Comment: Yes, cppdebug.dll is missing from `Common7\Packages\Debugger`. cppdebug.vsdconfig is also missing. Yesterday before reinstalling I re-downloaded the installer from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). Repairing the installation didn't help either. Also, when I completely uninstall my Visual Studio installation and try to reinstall it, the option for changing the installation path is greyed out and I'm unable to change it - it only allows me to install to the location that it was installed to on my previous Windows installation (2nd hard drive).

Comment: I was able to obtain a copy of those 2 files for 2 different versions of Visual Studio 2015. Placing them in the folder fixed the problem. The user should probably be notified of the .dll missing, if it fails to be loaded (seems to be loaded when you start the debugging). Should I open an issue report on Microsoft Connect?